# WinRT & XAML - Resource Files but for a language not localization?

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-runtime

Roughly, reading up on localization and Visual Studio 2012 C# and XAML for a windows store app pointed me here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329.aspx

This shows how to create a resource file for, say, en-US and fr-FR, which are US English and France French.  Shows you how to use the the resource loader to load it.  That's good and using the UID in Xaml page to load it automatically.

However, my confusion comes with, say, I want to create a Spanish resource file.  But I want to have it used for any spanish language localization.  If I set it up for mx-ES, what happens if the localization is pe-Es for Peruvian Spanish or es-ES for Spain Spanish.  Basically, i am a little confused on how I make 1 resource apply to all English or all French or all Spanish without it being bound by the country and without having to make a seperate resource file for every country/language combination.

I thought this would be an easy question, but I haven't seen where anyone has asked it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just the language code for the culture so ES instead of es-ES.

Comment: so, put it in strings/es/resources.resw rather than strings/mx-es/resources.resw ... the xaml files will work it out based on how they are in the link?